# Android Problem with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am kind of new to android programming, and I had to reinstall eclipse because there was a problem. Now, Eclipse isn't recognizing any android commands or there are red exclamation points next to the folders. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there can be multiple reasons to this..

The red exclamation mark basically means that something is wrong on the build path of the affected project. Check "context menu > Build Path > Configure Build Path..." 
(e.g. make sure you have the right JRE System Library on the Libraries 
tab). Or open the Problems view, group by Java Problem Type, and check 
the Fatal Errors.

The build path is stored in the .classpath file. Maybe you find the 
problem when you check the file's contents before and after "switching" 
Android API levels.

if problem persists

Try reinstalling the jre,jdk,android sdk again

Answer (score 1):

The same red exclamation appeared on my project i tried to open all jar files in my library with 7-Zip i replaced the ones telling corrupt, now the exclamation is gone

Answer (score 0):

Make you sure you have installed also the ADT plugin and set the android sdk path correctly from Window > Preferences > Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the gen folder. When you delete that folder eclipse will recreate it.